# How to store the output of scipy.griddata in a file for later purpose

Tags: python, python-2.7, grid, scipy, ipython

I have 4 co-ordinates a,b,c,d(in arrays) and corresponding data. I am interpolating the data over a grid using scipy.griddata over a range of values of these 4 co-ordinates. Now I want to store the whole grid and the interpolated data values in such a way that I can call it later with some function which will take the co-ordinates as the function parameter and return me the data value corresponding to them. What is the easiest way to do?